# How to use RESTful APIs in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-4, restful-url

Currently I am using APIs as follows

```
   Route::any('api/v1/unsubscribe','SubscriberController@unsubscribe');
   Route::any('api/v1/getdata','SubscriberController@getdata');
   Route::any('api/v1/setdata','SubscriberController@setdata');
```

My database is MongoDB. I think this has no security, How can I implement using RESTful more securely in Laravel 4.

Comment: I have got what i was expecting from @nozzleman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Samer Shaikh already pointed out, **Resource Controllers** would be the first thing you should consider to use.

To address your security concerns: I would recommend using an Route Filter on the Routes you'd like to protect. In your given screnario, this could look sth. like that;

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'auth.basic'], function()
{
    Route::resource('subscription', 'SubscriberController'); 
});
```

I'd like to give another tip regarding your route URI's. This isn't really a RESTful way to address your resources, as it would be hard to stay consistent within your API. Better use the standard-routes generated by `Route::resource(..)`, this makes it easier for you to develop and for developers to understand your API since resources are being adressed consistently this way.

Answer (score 1):

There is enough laravel documentation to understand restfull controllers.
Please check the link below

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers